# how to expand a yasnippet snippet after punctuation?

Tags: yasnippet

**Q:** how can I get `yasnippet` snippets to expand when placed immediately after punctuation?

Consider the snippet `SNIP`.  It will expand if preceded by whitespace (eg, `here's a SNIP` expands), but not when preceded immediately by an alphanumeric character (eg, `here's a superSNIP` does not expand).

Snippets also expand after parentheses and braces, so these all expand:

- `here's a (SNIP`
- `here's a [SNIP`
- `here's a {SNIP`

However, snippets do not seem to expand after punctuation, so, eg, neither `here's a ;SNIP` nor `here's a .SNIP` will expand.

I imagine there's a good reason for this, but I'd like to know how to get snippets to fire after punctuation characters (or, more generally, non-alphanumeric characters).  Ideally, this could be mode-specific or buffer-local.

Comment: Perhaps your major-mode defines the period as having a certain syntax that is not contemplated by `yas-key-syntaxes` [*"List of character syntaxes used to find a trigger key before point*.]?  The default value is:  `(list "w" "w_" "w_." "w_.()" "^ ")`  Check the syntax value of the period in your particular major mode by placing the cursor at that position and typing `C-u C-x =`  If appropriate, you could try adding that particular syntax to the list above.  [This is all just a guess.]